# use two "schedules" in one "source" block in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am modeling a production process for my thesis. in this model I have two products (A & B) that are using same material so I have to inject the common material by schedule1 (Production Plan For Product A) and also schedule B.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, welcome to SOF! This is not a good way of asking a question. Your question shows zero research. First of all, why do you need two schedules in one source? Think of the real production.. do the raw materials all appear at once and product is generated?

Comment: Welcome Mohamad, some tips to improve your question here: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two different schedules and two different source blocks all feeding into 1 queue. This will allow you to have two separate arrivals for the separate production plans. See example below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution

Make your sources a population

[image: source]

And then make a collection of all your schedules and do the following:

[image: collection]
and now you can have as many sources as you want with as many schedules as you need

Comment: Thank you for helping me, can you please give me some more guide lines for using collection in this way?